# Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action Error

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, ms-office, ole

I frequently receive ok-only prompts while automating add-ins in Excel, stating that Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action Error. How to use Interop.dll to show a custom message and handle this error programmatically. Before receiving the prompt[enter link description here](https://im.ge/i/ole.urr57x)

Answer (score 0):

While You possibly can catch these exceptions depending on your automation framework and do something with it - these type of errors typically comes from not closing the files properly when changing from one to another.

Make sure you dispose all that can be disposed and close all which can be closed in reverse order obviously and it should go away.

If You need more details do post your code for opening and closing looks like a bug there which will make it not coming up.

You do not technically have to use interop, could you consider using a more modern package for interacting with excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google drive / file stream then this may be the problem. Turn off "Real Time Presence in Microsoft Office" then the messages go away.